# Restriction of dual basis to subspaces.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let V be a finite dimensional vector space and f_1,..,f_m be a linearly indepedent in V*. Prove that the following two statements are equivalent.
(i)f_1,..,f_m is a basis of V*.
(ii)for every subspace W of V, the restrictions of f_1,..,f_m to W spans W*

Here is what I have so far.

(i)=>(ii). We want to show that for a $T\in W^*$, $T=c_1*f_1+...+c_m*f_m$. Let $w\in W\subseteq V$. Let $\{v_1,..,v_m\}$ be a basis of V. Since w is also in V, we can write $w=a_1*v_1+...+a_m*v_m$ for some scalars $a_i$.

LHS:$T(w)=a_1*T(v_1)+...+a_m*T(v_m)$
RHS: $(c_1*f_1+...+c_m*f_m)(w)=c_1*f_1(w)+...+c_m*f_m(w)= c_1*a_1+...+c_m*a_m.$

Therefore if we let $T(v_i)=c_i$, then LHS=RHS which implies f_1,..,f_m spans W*.

I don't know how to do (ii)=>(i)
Thanks

Comment: What are your thoughts/work on the problem so far? The more information you give us, the better we can tailor our answers to your needs.

Comment: I recommend that you [edit] that into your question.

Comment: I tried my best to explain what I have so far. Thank you Cameron

Answer (score 1):

Part 2.  To show: If V is a vector space of dimension m and  {$f_1, f_2, ... f_m$} = S  span $W^*$ for every subspace W of V, then S is a basis of $V^*$.

If dim(V) = m then dim($V^*$) = m also.

Let $W_1$ be a subspace of V with dimension m - 1, By hypothesis S spans $W_1^*$  So there must be m-1 independent elements S, call them $S_1$ = {$f_1, f_2, ...  f_{m-1}$} that form a basis for $W_1^*$.

There are m distinct subspaces $W_i$ of V with dimension m - 1, and for each of these S spans $W_i^*$.  However each $W_i$ is different and therefore each $W_i^*$ is different -- that is, no two of them can have the same basis. (This is because $W_i^{**} = W_i$.) So in each case we must pick a different set of m-1 elements of S to form a basis for $W_i^*$.

Let U be a subspace of dimension 1 such that $W \bigcap U$ = 0.  Then some element g of S must be the basis for $U^*$.  There must be at least one of the  $W_i^*$, call it W whose basis does not include g. We have W $\bigcup$ U = V so that $V^*$ =$(W \bigcup U)^*$ = $W^* \bigcup U^*$.  So the basis for $V^*$ is the union of the basis for W and g; and that is S.

Comment: Since we haven't learnt that the dual operator distributes over unions, the final part is a little bit unclear for me. Thank you for your response Betty.

Comment: Also, where do you use the fact that $S$ is the set of restricted functions?

Comment: You bring up good points, and I agree I didn't nail those things down.  Re dual operator distributes over unions I think that may not generally be true, because the union can include an overlap.  However, this is a union of disjoint subspaces and I think it works.   I agree I didn't prove it, and will try to answer later.

Comment: Re the restriction of the functions, I was thinking it is just a formality -- that if the function is operating on a subspace it is automatically restricted.  But I now see that I've proved only the independence of the restricted functions and haven't extended it to the full functions.   I'll put some time into both points today; and maybe you can look around to see what is out there.

Comment: I am pretty sure this is the right kind of way to go about this, and suspect there is some known trick which is unknown to me, that simplifies it or pulls it all together.

Comment: okay, about the restriction of $f_i$ to the subspaces. These are all linear functions and if a set is independent restricted to a subspace, it is independent on the whole space. If you can't find a linear combination of them that adds up to 0 on the subspace, adding one more term to the function isn't going to make any difference.  If they are independent as ax + by, then they are independent as ax + by + cz.  So I just have to work on the union problem.